# compiled query only scalar parameters are allowed !

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using POCO objects in EF 4 without any T4 template generation.

I have a DataContext class that encapsulates all ObjectSets, something like this

```
 public sealed class DataContext :IDisposable
 {

 public IObjectSet GetObjectSet() where T : MyBase
 {

   object objectSet = null;

   this.objectSets.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out objectSet);

   if (objectSet == null)
   {
    objectSet = this.context.CreateObjectSet();
    this.objectSets.Add(typeof(T), objectSet);
   }
   return (IObjectSet)objectSet;
  }

  public ObjectContext ObjectContext
  {            
     get
       { 
       return this.context; 
      }  
  }
}
```

When i write  the following compiled query and try to pass in this class as one of the parameters, it gives me a runtime error saying only scalar parameters are allowed

```
static readonly Func<ObjectContext , DataContext, string, int?> getOperationByOrchestrationName

  = CompiledQuery.Compile(

  (ObjectContext ctx, DataContext container, string name) =>

   (from or in container.GetObjectSet<MyOrClass>()

   join op in container.GetObjectSet<MyOpClass>()

   on or.Id equals op.Id

   where op.Name == name
   select op.Id).FirstOrDefault()

  );
```

If i modify the query like this  it works, but i deeply suspect its being compiled every time, since i am not seeing the performance boost i would see from a compiled query, can someone point out whats going on ?

```
    static readonly Func, IObjectSet, string, IQueryable> 
   getOperationByOrchestrationName   
    = CompiledQuery.Compile(
      (ObjectContext ctx, IObjectSet ors, IObjectSet ops,string operationName) =>
       from or in ors
       join op in ops
       on or.Id equals op.Id
       where op.Name == name
       select op.Id
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested, if you return IQueryable from compiled query and call any of the methods that can change the query ( singleordefault, or firstordefault etc), you would not get benefit of a compiled query.